# Tips on asp.net data updates and third party framework

Tags: asp.net, database, data-migration

I am supposed to create an data transfer utility that is to take data from an external source. in this case it's another database, and import/update data into an asp.net website database.

Now, the database and the site were created by another party and they already have an API/framework to access the database.

I've tried to write code on the site that imports the data but it sometimes times out and the app pool recycles.

How do I run a data transfer without timeouts and using the third part API so I don't have to re-write a ton of code?

Couple of notes: The API doesn't work outside of a web-site. It crashes and throws errors. Also, the users may want a user interface to run the data transfer manually.

Comment: Nobody has run into this before?

Comment: It's not that nobody has run into this, its you are lacking a lot of details in your question.  In most cases, you can set a timeout period on the application side but without more information and sample code and with us not being familiar with your framework how do you really expect us to help?

Comment: How much detail do you need here? Have you ever worked with a framework that you couldn't edit, was limited to working only within a website, and you had to push data from another source? Is setting the timeout then the best way to handle this? Do you need to know every class within the framework, or the entire database schema?